# Why do I get different results in R from Stata for survey statistics?

Tags: r, stata, survey

I'm trying to recreate survey statistics from Stata code in R, but I can't get the confidence intervals to come out the same. I'm subsetting the data by the county of interest, and then looking at what percent of student respondents don't wear bike helmets, split by grade, and what the confidence intervals are for those percents.
In the Stata code, we set the survey weights and create a frequency table with confidence intervals:

```
svyset psu [pweight = fwt_cnty], strata(strata) singleunit(centered)
svy, subpop(if c_valencia==1): tab grade helmet, per ci format(%8.1f) nomarginals vertical
```

The results look like this:

```
------------------------------
          |Bike helmet: Rarely
          |      or never     
    Grade | SmeTime+   NvrRrly
----------+-------------------
      9th |    17.09     82.91
          |     5.66     58.55
          |    41.45     94.34
          | 
     10th |    10.19     89.81
          |     5.78     82.64
          |    17.36     94.22
          | 
     11th |    7.834     92.17
          |    3.498     83.38
          |    16.62      96.5
          | 
     12th |    11.28     88.72
          |    4.559     74.71
          |    25.29     95.44
------------------------------
Key: Row percentage
     Lower 95% confidence bound for row percentage
     Upper 95% confidence bound for row percentage

  Pearson:
    Uncorrected   chi2(3)         =    4.8590
    Design-based  F(1.74, 36.57)  =    0.5336     P = 0.5666
```

The following R code should do the same thing as far as I can tell:

```
yrrs_cnty <- svydesign(id=~psu, strata=~strata, weights=~fwt_cnty, data=yrbss_hs_NM)
options(survey.lonely.psu = "adjust")
CITable <- svyby(~helmet,~{cntytxt=={params$counties}}+grade, yrrs_cnty, svyciprop, vartype ="ci", na.rm.all=T)
```

The results look like this:

```
        {     cntytxt == {         params$counties     } } grade    helmet      ci_l      ci_u
FALSE.1                                              FALSE     1 0.7884086 0.7634557 0.8113797
TRUE.1                                                TRUE     1 0.8291318 0.4233797 0.9697601
FALSE.2                                              FALSE     2 0.7946815 0.7652980 0.8212456
TRUE.2                                                TRUE     2 0.8980533 0.7114234 0.9692088
FALSE.3                                              FALSE     3 0.8127924 0.7889255 0.8345267
TRUE.3                                                TRUE     3 0.9216650 0.8040353 0.9712142
FALSE.4                                              FALSE     4 0.8057442 0.7737261 0.8342026
TRUE.4                                                TRUE     4 0.8871825 0.7264505 0.9588247
```

After applying the weights from the survey design, R produces the same percentages for each grade, (81.91, 89.81, 91.17, & 88.72) but the confidence intervals are much larger. Does anyone have ideas as to why? Both should be calculating a confidence interval for a proportion. I've tried casting the variables as factors, but that didn't seem to help either. Does anyone have ideas as to what is causing the difference in results?

Comment: You might want to check that both Stata and R are calculating the same type of confidence interval. There are at least four different types of confidence intervals for proportions (e.g. Wald, Clopper-Pearson, Wilson, Agresti-Coull), which will each produce slightly different values. A quick Google finds this article that might be helpful: https://towardsdatascience.com/five-confidence-intervals-for-proportions-that-you-should-know-about-7ff5484c024f

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's hard to check this without the data.  According to the Stata documentation, it's using the same basic confidence interval calculation that is the default for `svyciprop`: a Wald interval on the logit scale.

I used an example from the Stata manual to check

```
webuse nhanes2f
svyset psuid [pweight=finalwgt], strata(stratid)
svy: tab rural diabetes, per ci nomarginals vertical row
```

which gives

```
(running tabulate on estimation sample)

Number of strata   =        31                Number of obs     =       10,335
Number of PSUs     =        62                Population size   =  116,997,257
                                              Design df         =           31

------------------------
          |  diabetes,  
1=rural,  | 1=yes, 0=no 
0=urban   |     0      1
----------+-------------
        0 | 96.63  3.374
          |  96.2  2.991
          | 97.01  3.804
          | 
        1 | 96.45  3.547
          | 95.62  2.867
          | 97.13   4.38
------------------------
  Key:  row percentage
        lower 95% confidence bound for row percentage
        upper 95% confidence bound for row percentage

  Pearson:
    Uncorrected   chi2(1)         =    0.2027
    Design-based  F(1, 31)        =    0.1794     P = 0.6748
```

In R I get

```
dhanes<-svydesign(id=~psuid, strata=~stratid, weights=~finalwgt, data=nhanes, nest=TRUE)
svyby(~diabetes,~rural, design=dhane, svyciprop, vartype="ci",method="logit",na.rm=TRUE)
```

giving

```
  rural   diabetes       ci_l       ci_u
0     0 0.03373569 0.02990043 0.03804360
1     1 0.03546713 0.02858347 0.04393358
```

That's close. Stata and R are using different defaults for the denominator degrees of freedom: Stata is using the design df for the whole sample and R is using the design df for the subpopulation.  Making R use the whole-sample df gives almost perfect agreement

```
> svyby(~diabetes,~rural, design=dhanes, svyciprop, vartype="ci",method="logit",na.rm=TRUE,df=degf(dhanes))
  rural   diabetes       ci_l       ci_u
0     0 0.03373569 0.02990532 0.03803744
1     1 0.03546713 0.02867079 0.04380188
```

So what's happening in your example? I don't know. It might be single-PSU strata, or different missing-value handling or something. It probably needs more information to work out, though